# UITextField Not Moving to Correct Location with Keyboard Launch

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview, uikeyboard

I am trying to make the UITextField move so it sits on top of the keyboard (the same as iMessage), but can not figure out what my issue is. I have reviewed questions similar to this one, but have been unsuccessful thus far. The text field appears to move slightly, but ends up behind the keyboard, so hopefully it is a silly coordinate placement issue that someone can point out to me. Another thing to note is that the GIF below is on an iPhone X, however, when I run the app on an iPhone 6 the UITextField moves to the correct location above the keyboard, but moves back underneath it as soon as I type anything.  Any help is appreciated!

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var messageView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var textMessageField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var contactStatusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var videoChatButton: UIButton!
let cellID = "cellID"
var contactIsOnline = false
var currentUser:G8User = G8User()
var currentContact:G8User = G8User()
var currentConversation : Conversation?
var videoToken = ""
var allMessages : [ChatMessage] = []
var onlineRef:DatabaseReference!
var incomingMessagesRef:DatabaseReference!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sendButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0/255), green: CGFloat(137.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(249.0/255.0), alpha: 1)
    sendButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    videoChatButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    videoChatButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    collectionView.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    // Used to dismiss keyboard
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)



    // Set up keyboard observers
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChatViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChatViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


}

 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("SHOWING KEYBOARD")
     // TODO: Adjust scrolling for message view
     if let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue{

        let topOfMessageBox = keyboardFrame.origin.y - self.messageView.frame.height
         self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: collectionView.frame.origin.x,y: collectionView.frame.origin.y,width: collectionView.frame.width,height: topOfMessageBox - collectionView.frame.origin.y)
        self.messageView.frame = CGRect(x: messageView.frame.origin.x,y: topOfMessageBox,width: messageView.frame.width, height: messageView.frame.height)


     }
 }

 @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("HIDING KEYBOARD")

    self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: collectionView.frame.origin.x,y: collectionView.frame.origin.y,width: collectionView.frame.width,height:  messageView.frame.origin.y - collectionView.frame.origin.y )
    self.messageView.frame = CGRect(x: messageView.frame.origin.x,y: self.view.frame.maxY - messageView.frame.size.height,width: messageView.frame.width,height: messageView.frame.height)
 }
```

[GIF of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRngY.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `UIView` extension something like `myTextField.bindToKeyboard()`

```
extension UIView {

    func bindToKeyboard() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {

        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        let beginningFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let endFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        var deltaY = endFrame.origin.y - beginningFrame.origin.y

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I really like this implementation, however, the same problem persists. Referring to the original implmentation: The messageView will move to the top of the keyboard now, but whenever I tap the keyboard ,the messageView just moves to the bottom of the screen underneath the keyboard. The weird thing is neither the keyboardWillHide or keyboardWillShow functions are triggered and there is no other part of my code that sets the position of the messageView. I can not figure out what is causing this